# Havok Project Anarchy game engine duplicate symbol with Google Analytics lib

Tags: ios, game-engine, havok

I'm currently support a customer to integrated our SDK. Our customer making a game with Project Anarchy game engine which provided by Havok.

The problem is, when they're build the project xcode show the error message:

[image]

Our SDK use Google Analytics static lib for tracking users when playing game and their game engine used it too.
This is the first time I faced this problem because our other customers use Unity or Cocos2dx most.

So, does anyone know how to solve this problem? I was think I need to change in my SDK but we're in rush hour and changing SDK take a lot of time for testing and bugs fix and I wanna find an easy way.

Thank in advance.

Comment: did you install it by Cocoapod? If yes, did you install framework with `static_framework`

Comment: @QuocNguyen No, I download GA lib from google analytics website. Not using cocoapod in our SDK